# TensorBoard GPU profiling with Tensorflow Agents

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, tensorboard

I would like to profile my GPU usage when training agents from [tensorflow/agents](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents), but I cannot figure out how. Specifically I am trying to profile my GPU when running this [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/blob/master/tf_agents/agents/sac/examples/v2/train_eval.py).

It seems that the TensorBoard profiler requires TensorBoard callbacks to be used like so:

```py
# Create a TensorBoard callback
logs = "logs/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

tboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir = logs,
                                                 histogram_freq = 1,
                                                 profile_batch = '500,520')

model.fit(ds_train,
          epochs=2,
          validation_data=ds_test,
          callbacks = [tboard_callback])
```

However no `fit` methods are called when training a TF Agent. They are trained using a `train` method that accepts no `callbacks` argument, which can be seen [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/blob/v0.12.0/tf_agents/agents/tf_agent.py#L294-L338).

Is there another way to get the TensorBoard profiler to work when training an agent from the Tensorflow Agents library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tf.profiler` module, which is what the TensorBoard callback does [under the hood](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.8.0/keras/callbacks.py#L2608-L2637).

The agent example you linked uses a custom training loop, one possibility would be to use the profiler this way:

```
# to customize based on the number of steps you want to profile 
start_profiling_step = 50
stop_profiling_step = 100
profiling_log_dir = "./profile_logs"
while global_step_val < num_iterations:
  # rest of the training code
  # ...
  if global_step_val == start_profiling_step:
    tf.profiler.experimental.start(logdir=profiling_log_dir)
  if global_step_val == stop_profiling_step:
    tf.profiler.experimental.stop(save=True)
```

You can look at the [documentation of the `tf.profiler` module](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/profiler/experimental) for more information.